# Select child of a OneToMany reletionship in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true )
    private String token;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;
```

with a OneToMany relation to this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private long id;

    private double time;
    private String date;
```

Now, how does the JPQL Query look like if i want to get all Tasks from a Person with the date "2014-12-12" ?

Comment: try adding a ManyToOne to the `Task` entity, but if you do not need the Person, then simply do a findByProperty on the Task.date

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How exactly would i do the findByProperty? Can you give me an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true )
    private String token;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    private double time;
    private String date;
}

select t from Task t where t.person.id = ? and t.date = ?
```